# can we use .add() for appending objects.?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code,

```
var elementsToBeAppended = $();

for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  elementsToBeAppended.add($('<div>'));
}

alert(elementsToBeAppended.length);
```

I just expected that the above code will alert 10 but it is alerting 0, I actually trying to group that object in that variable and then i would like to append it to the DOM in order to avoid using .append() for each iterations.

Can anybody tell me, Am i thinking in a wrong way.? If so just guide me to the correct way.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/K4PtH/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like most jQuery methods, [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) **returns** a new object:

```
elementsToBeAppended = elementsToBeAppended.add($('<div>'));
```

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the `.add()` method **constructs a new jQuery object** from the union of those elements and the ones passed into the method.

And further below:

> The updated set of elements can be used in a following (chained)
>   method, or assigned to a variable for later use. For example:
>
> ```
> $( "p" ).add( "div" ).addClass( "widget" );
> var pdiv = $( "p" ).add( "div" );
> ```
>
> The following will not save the added elements, because the `.add()`
>   method creates a new set and leaves the original set in `pdiv`
>   unchanged:
>
> ```
> var pdiv = $( "p" );
> pdiv.add( "div" ); // WRONG, pdiv will not change
> ```

Reading documentation usually helps :)